# How to decrease memory usage for Android Studio (also works for Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, android-studio, memory

After some months using Android Studio, i was very upset of how much memory it was using:

- 2GB for the IDE
- 1GB for Gradle build
- ~1GB for a running Java app

How to decrease memory usage? (ANSWER BELOW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i tried one thing: i uninstalled all Java 64 bit and replaced by Java 32 Bit. Then i updated the JAVA_HOME to point to the new location and rebooted my Windows 10 notebook.

Android Studio already comes with the 32-bit flavor, but you need to download a specific 32-bit version of Eclipse.

Now i get this:

- ~1GB for the IDE
- 360MB for Gradle
- 120MB for a running Java app

I also downgraded FireFox to 32 bits, and now it takes half memory.

HTH,

guich

Comment: You should mark as accepted your own answer - its good practice and keeps your question from showing up as unanswered!  IMHO, you probably could have made some tweaks to the XMS/XMX memory settings for your environment(s) when running Gradle and Android Dev - I do the same thing in Eclipse